# DependencyProperty and caliburn, view model not updated by dependency property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, caliburn

I have a view which wraps a `TreeView`, called `MbiTreeView`. I want to get the selected item from the (wrapped) tree view in the view model.

The 'parent' user control which uses this custom user control:

```
<UserControl [...]>

    <views:MbiTreeView
        Grid.Row="0"
        cal:Bind.Model="{Binding TreeViewModel}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    </views:MbiTreeView>
</UserControl>
```

The parent user control is bound to this view model:

```
internal sealed class SomeViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    public IMbiTreeViewModel TreeViewModel { get; }

    public SomeViewModel(
        IMbiTreeViewModel treeViewModel)
    {
        TreeViewModel = treeViewModel;
    }
}
```

The MbiTreeView user control is rather straight forward. It subscribes to the selection changed event, and defines a few templates (not relevant for this question, so left them out in the question)

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged">
```

iew.ItemContainerStyle>

The code behind declares the dependency property:

```
public partial class MbiTreeView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SelectedItem),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MbiTreeView),
        null);

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public MbiTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

when I start the application, I can navigate through the tree view items. When I click on a treeview node, then the `OnSelectedItemChanged` event fires (I get into my breakpoint there). So everything goes fine up and until setting the value in the dependency property `SelectedItem`.

Then I would expect that the xaml binding gets notified, and updates the view model. But that never happens.

I am getting nowhere with this, help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectedItem Binding should be TwoWay:

```
<views:MbiTreeView ...
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

You could declare the property like shown below to make to bind TwoWay by default.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SelectedItem),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MbiTreeView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: Finally.... figured it out. Yes, you are correct, I should've made the binding twoway (great tip about the default behavior on dependency property, didn't know that yet). But, the problem is, that "somehow" the binding is bound to the TreeViewModel. The one set using `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding TreeViewModel}"`. I had that feeling, so I added the `SelectedItem` property on the `MbiTreeViewModel` too, and that one *does* hit the breakpoint.... So I went for a relative source binding and then it works!